# Why does calling super() in parent class __init__() change the subclass __init__() behavior?

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, superclass, super, method-resolution-order

I've been trying to understand the behavior of `super()` in the context of multiple inheritance.  I'm confused as to why the calls to `super()` in the parent classes in test2.py cause `__init__()` to be called for both parents?

**test1.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.A = "A"
        print self.A

class B(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.B = "B"
        print self.B

class C(A, B):

    def __init__(self):
        self.C = "C"
        print self.C
        super(C, self).__init__()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Without super() in parent __init__():"
    c = C()
    print c.__dict__
    print C.__mro__
```

produces:

```
$ ./test.py 
Without super() in parent __init__():
C
A
{'A': 'A', 'C': 'C'}
(<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <type 'object'>)
```

**test2.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.A = "A"
        print self.A
        super(A, self).__init__()

class B(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.B = "B"
        print self.B
        super(B, self).__init__()

class C(A, B):

    def __init__(self):
        self.C = "C"
        print self.C
        super(C, self).__init__()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "With super() in parent __init__():"
    c = C()
    print c.__dict__
    print C.__mro__
```

produces:

```
$ ./test2.py 
With super() in parent __init__():
C
A
B
{'A': 'A', 'C': 'C', 'B': 'B'}
(<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <type 'object'>)
```

Comment: " I'm confused as to why the calls to super() in the parent classes in test2.py cause __init__() to be called for both parents?" - Because that's the whole point of `super()`: Ensuring that all classes in the hierarchy gets called, in the right order.

Comment: @LennartRegebro I realize this now that I've read the answer from @BrenBarn and this post https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/  I was confused because I thought that `super()` would unconditionally call the parent class (which in the case of `A` and `B` is `object`).  It was surprising for me to discover that the `super()` call in `A.__init__()` actually calls `B.__init__()` (which then calls `object.__init__()`)due to the MRO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your mistake is in your comment:

```
super(C, self).__init__()  <-- call to object.__init__()
```

This is not a call to `object.__init__`.  The reason that you pass both the class C and the instance `self` to `super` is so that it knows what to call next, not just based on the superclasses of the class, but based on the MRO of the instance.  Essentially, `super(C, self).__init__` means "call the `__init__` of the class after C in self's MRO".

This is the whole point of `super` --- it allows cooperative inheritance where a class can just call `super` to mean "pass control the next class in the MRO", without needing to know at class definition time which class that is.

So when you call `super(C, self).__init__`, that calls `A.__init__`, because A is the next class after C in the MRO.  Then when A calls `super(A, self).__init__`, that calls `B.__init__`, because B is the class after A in the MRO.

(Note that your messages are printed in reverse order --- B, A, C --- because you print each message *after* calling the superclass method.  So the first message doesn't get printed until executing gets all the way up to `B.__init__`, and then the other messages are printed on the way back down the inheritance tree.)

Comment: thanks for the helpful answer!  That comment was unintentional in class C (I had intended to placed it in class A, which I now realize is also wrong...).  I was originally confused because I didn't understand MRO for the instance, and thought that both A and B would always call object.__init__() instead of following the MRO.  I removed the incorrect comments from the original question and reordered the calls to super so that it prints correctly (so that I don't unintentionally confuse somebody coming across this later on down the road).  Feel free to update your answer to match.